# possible to use a ComposeView in an Android Service?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-service

I have a service that is an Application Overlay. I haven't gotten very far, but was able to present a Button on the screen using the service. I decided to try to use a ComposeView instead of a Button, but get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
```

It looks to me like LifecycleOwners must be an Activity, Fragment, or Dialog. So it may be that what I am trying to do is impossible and I'm stuck with older UI elements. Please let me know if there are any other possibilities, because I would rather use Jetpack Compose if I can.

```
class OverlayService : Service() {

    private var wm: WindowManager? = null
    private var button: Button? = null
    private var composeView: ComposeView? = null

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onCreate()

        val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel1")
            .build()

        startForeground(1, notification)

        wm = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager

        button = Button(this)
        button?.text = "Button"
        button?.alpha = 1f
        button?.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)

        composeView = getComposeView()

        val type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY

        val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, type, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)
        params.gravity = Gravity.START or Gravity.BOTTOM
        params.x = 0
        params.y = 0
        //wm?.addView(button, params)
        wm?.addView(composeView, params)

        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    fun getComposeView(): ComposeView {
        return ComposeView(this).apply {
            setContent {
                Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(start = 1.dp, end = 1.dp)
                )
                {
                    Text("Hello World", fontSize = 30.sp)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: There's a [LifecycleService](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleService) helper specifically for making a `Service` a `LifecycleOwner`. Is there a reason you aren't using that?

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you resolve this problem?

Comment: @AlexandraFilyakova, my requirements changed just after I wrote the question and it became a moot point for me. But it looks like Ian's suggestion above is workable.